# niceness of a background process

Tags: linux, background-process, nohup, nice

Do background process have different nice given? I noticed it is not having the default 0. This might be a problem because it is having less priority.. does anyone know how to change this behavior? I run the java via below start script and no there is no `nice` called inside that script.

`nohup ./start.sh &`

```
F S   UID    PID   PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  5330  12759      1  0  84   4 -  3283 -      ?        00:00:00 start.sh
0 S  5330  12772  12759  1  84   4 - 1462473 -    ?        00:19:12 java
```

Comment: What shell are you using? The `ksh` shell has a `bgnice` shell option that, when it is set, means that any background job will have a nicer niceness value.

Comment: The user is using ``ksh`` but i explicitly use ``#!/bin/sh`` in the script.

Comment: Are they maybe either starting the script as `ksh ./thescript` or maybe as `./thescript &`?

Comment: Well not exactly like that. It is being started as ``nohup ./thescript &``.

Comment: So, if it's started in the background, from a `ksh` shell, with the `bgnice` option set, then this will be why the niceness value is not zero. The only remaining question from me is whether the `bgnice` option _is_ set or not.

Comment: Does this validate what you're saying?

user@server:/home/user> set -o | grep bgnice
bgnice                   on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user running this script is starting it in the background from an interactive `ksh` shell session.

The `ksh` shell has a shell option called `bgnice`, which in `ksh93` is on *by default*, which causes the shell to start background jobs with a non-zero niceness value (it will be 4 higher than the shell the job is started from).

This is from the `ksh93` manual:

> `bgnice`  All background jobs are run at a lower priority.
>          This is the default mode.

To turn this option off, use

```
set +o bgnice
```

In some variants of the `ksh` shell (e.g. `pdksh`, and *possibly* `mksh`), the option is still available, but *not* set by default.